# Matlab : How to implement a vectorized version for L1 distance calculation

Tags: matlab, hamming-distance

I want to calculate the Hamming distance between vectors which are very high dimensional. A data point is a vector called as the feature. Assuming, each  component `f_i` as an integer, it is represented in its binary form having say `j` bits. There are `n = 900` feature components for each data point. The problem formulation is

[image: Problem]

The formula for Hamming distance between 2 different vectors is given in the picture below where `j = number of bits`

[image: formula]

For ex let `n = 10` feature components,

```
f = [3,4,1,4,5,6,6,7,1,14];
g = [1,3,5,6,7,8,11,3,10,2];
```

Each component / element of the array is represented by its 16 bit binary representation using `dec2bin(f_i,l)`

I tried using  `dist = sum((f-g).^2,2)* 1/2^l` where l= 16 bits but this does not make sense because there are 2 summations in the formula.

Comment: Your `f` has 11 elements, `g` has 10, and both should be two-dimensional. Can you explain?

Comment: In my application, they are two dimensional and not integer valued. I wanted to know how to compute distance so that I can later expand it to my full application

Comment: So why are you giving a 1d example if in your application you have 2d?

Comment: My impression came from your attempt: you have 1/2^l in your expression, but that factor appears as `2^(-j)` in the mathematical formula. Where `j` is the second dimension of `b_{ij}`! That's why I was asking. If you have 2d arrays `bf` and `bg`, it's as easy as a matrix-vector product to compute `abs(bf-bg)*1./(2.^(1:l)).'` or something similar, then sum that twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want is

```
sum(bitxor(f,g))/2^l
```

where `l=16`